# Why does Iterator have a contains method but Iterable does not, in Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I would like to call 'contains' on my Iterables :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason `Iterable` does not have a `contains` method is because the way it is defined can have direct consequences on variance. Basically, there are two type signatures that make sense for it:

```
def contains(v: Any): Boolean
def contains(v: A): Boolean
```

The second definition has increased type safety. However, `A`, which is the type parameter of collection, appears in a contra-variant position, which forces the collection to be invariant. It *could* be defined like this:

```
def contains[B >: A](v: B): Boolean
```

but that wouldn't offer any improvement over the first signature, using `Any`.

As a consequence of this, you'll see that `immutable.Seq` is co-variant and uses the first signature, while `immutable.Set` is invariant and uses the second signature.

Comment: Note: `contains` **is** implemented using the signature `contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1)` in `SeqLike` (at least in Scala 2.11.8). I do not think this is the same as using `Any` - it places some constraints on the `B` type - you can pass `Any`, but you cannot pass a type which is known to be unrelated.

Comment: @Suma Sure you can. Go ahead and try. If you pass an unrelated type, `A1` will be inferred to be the common supertype. And because everything is descendant from `Any`, then all types have a common supertype with each other.

Comment: You are right. Is there any reason why is the signature in the library as it is, and not with `Any`, as you write, then?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why `contains` is not defined on `Iterable` or `TraversableOnce`, but you could easily define it yourself:

```
class TraversableWithContains[A](underlying: TraversableOnce[A]) {
  def contains(v: Any): Boolean =
    underlying.exists(_ == v)
}
implicit def addContains[A](i: Iterable[A]) = new TraversableWithContains(i)
```

and use it as if it were defined on Iterable:

```
val iterable: Iterable[Int] = 1 to 4
assert(iterable.contains(3))
assert(!iterable.contains(5))
```