# I'm looking for a contains like method for iterable

Tags: java, contains, iterable

I have an Iterable and I need to check about a specific string inside the iterable. I tried `iter.contains("my string")`, but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: We need additional informations (just like this comment needs more data about what kind of data we need).

Comment: Can you show some more code? What exactly is that `iter` referring to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925765/why-does-iterator-have-a-contains-method-but-iterable-does-not-in-scala-2-8

Comment: If the class is actually derived from `Collection` I suppose you can upcast and then call `contains` on the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
iter.toString().toLowerCase().equals("my string")
```

Comment: That's not the question, I think he wants to do this without iterating through the elements... Why is a mystery, but there it is.

Comment: Ok. I think the problem like he tried to iterate element and compare with `iter` object directly.

Comment: @VTT so this was about `Iterator` and not `Iterable`?

Comment: That is quite an ugly hack which assumes that the specific iterable implements `toString` in a "user-friendly" way. Although it is generally the case you should not rely on that.

Comment: Yes . He accepted my answer so I think that He concern with `Iterator`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my mistake and lack of knowledge.

Comment: This is a poor solution.  The toString function on the iterator iterface doesn't necessarily return the string representation of all its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Iterable is an interface, it doesn't contain a method like contains because that would assume the underlying data structure could be read sequentially without corruption.

Neither are assumptions the Iterable interface makes.

Answer (score 3):

Your only real option with a bare `Iterable` is to do a bare `for` loop:

```
 for (String string : iterable) {
   if (string.equals(foo)) {
     return true;
   }
 }
 return false;
```

...or you could call another method which does essentially the same thing, e.g. Guava's `Iterables.contains(Iterable, Object)`.

Answer (score 2):

The Interface Iterable only returns an Iterator. So it is not possible to directly obtain if a certain value is inside. Instead you have to iterate using a for-each structure e.g.

```
boolean found = false;
for (String s: iter) {
    if (s.equals("my string")) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Depending on the Size this may not be very efficient. But if its your only choice...it will work at least.

Comment: Multiple mistakes in there, Björn, such as `string` instead of `String` and using `==` instead of `equals()` on a `String`.

Comment: @owlstead: You are right. Thanks for the comment! I corrected the errors.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a iterator object and there is a contains method for iterators in most programming languages

This is a very similar question that has a been answered here
[Why does Iterator have a contains method but Iterable does not, in Scala 2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925765/why-does-iterator-have-a-contains-method-but-iterable-does-not-in-scala-2-8)

Comment: Yes, but this was about Java...