# Why does Scala have SeqView but not SetView?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Given that `Seq.view` returns a `SeqView`, I would have expected `Set.view` to return a `SetView`, but no such view exists; `Set.view` instead returns an `IterableView`.

Unfortunately, `IterableView` is missing some methods, such as `contains`. Compare these, for example:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).view.map(_ * 2).contains(4) // returns true
Set(1, 2, 3).view.map(_ * 2).contains(4) // error
```

Is there any particular reason why no `SetView` class exists?

Also, is there any reason why `Iterable` doesn't have a `contains` method (given this is basically a special case of find)?

Given the situation above, is there a better alternative to this when working with sets (in other words, what is the best practice in Scala):

```
Set(1, 2, 3).view.map(_ * 2).find(_ == 4).isDefined
```

Comment: About contains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925765/why-does-iterator-have-a-contains-method-but-iterable-does-not-in-scala-2-8

Comment: Not quite general alternative, but `Set(1, 2, 3).exists(x => x * 2 == 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `SetView` because views are a pain in the neck to implement and test, and that effort is less worth it since the nice properties of sets generally require you to have already eagerly created the entire set (e.g. `O(1)` or `O(log n)` lookup).

`contains` isn't in `Iterable` precisely because `Set` extends `Iterable` and a `Set` `contains` should not type check unless you ask for something that could be in the set.  Since `Iterable` is covariant, its `contains` would have to admit you asking for anything (as the `contains` for `Seq` does).

As a workaround, you can note that `contains(x)` does the same thing as `exists(_ == x)`, and `exists` is on `Iterable`.