# Why is "contains" implemented in Seq, but not in Iterable or Traversable?

Tags: scala, containers

Following does not work:

```
val t: Traversable[Int] = Seq(0, 1, 2)

t contains 0
```

Even changing `Traversable` to `Iterable` does not help. One needs to use `Seq`, or `t exists (_ == 0)`.

When checking the implementation, `contains` is implemented in `SeqLike` as follows:

```
def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean = exists (_ == elem)
```

As `exists` is already implemented for `Traversable`, why not `contains`?

Comment: Its variance. See this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925765/why-does-iterator-have-a-contains-method-but-iterable-does-not-in-scala-2-8